# How can I use isinstance() here instead of comparing types?

Tags: python

I`m trying to compare these two variables and pylint gives me an error.

I have no ideea how to do it without comparing types.

```
for key in first_dict.keys():
    if type(first_dict[key]) != type(second_dict[key]):
        new_dict[key] = (first_dict[key], second_dict[key])
```

The error looks like this:

```
C: 13,11 Using type()instead of isinstance() for a typecheck. (unidiomatic-typecheck)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. They are not compared as equal, they are compared as different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not isinstance(first_dict[key], type(second_dict[key]))
```

Comment: Doesn't work. They are not compared as equal, they are compared as different.